# Why does providerRef return null?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React class

```
export class XElement extends BaseReactElement {
    private _providerRef = React.createRef<XProvider>();

    render () {
       return <XProvider ref={this._providerRef} />
    }

    create() {
       return this._providerRef!.createPending();
    }
 }
```

When a user clicks a button, create is called and providerRef is null, and it returns an error. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

The weird thing is that providerRef is not null on desktop, but as I resize the screen for mobile, it becomes null.

I'm guessing that providerRef has not been created yet and there's a race condition. Is there a way to wait until it has been created?

Comment: When is `create` being called?

Comment: it's called when a user fills out a text box.

Comment: What does `XProvider` do? If it renders `null` then the `ref` will be null.